# Gradle build fails when 'plugin.serialization' is added

Tags: kotlin, gradle

Gralde build of multi project fails with

```
mac> gradle build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':myKotlinMPLib'.
> Cannot add task 'commonizeNativeDistribution' as a task with that name already exists.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 588ms
3 actionable tasks: 3 up-to-date
```

Failure message when this line is added to one of the subproject build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
    //...
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.5.31"
}
```

settings.gradle.kts file

```
rootProject.name = "myTopLevelProject"
include("myKotlinMPLib", "myDependencyLib")
```

Command to reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/nickolay-kondratyev/glassthought-sandbox.git \
&& cd glassthought-sandbox \
&& git checkout kotlin_serializable_plugin_issue_stackoverflow \
&& cd simplified_top_level_project \
&& echo "------------------------------------------------------" \
&& ./gradlew build
```

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using? Can you add the full `build.gradle.kts` file? Kotlin version 1.5.31 is quite old, have you tried using a newer version?